# Operator norm vs spectral radius for positive matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, norms, spectral-radius

I believe the following statement should be true but somehow I don't see an argument:

For every integer $d>1$ there exists a constant $C=C(d)>1$ such that whenever $A$ is a $d \times d$ matrix with all entries integers $>0$, then

$$ \frac{1}{C} \|A\| \le \sigma(A) \le C \|A\|.$$

Here $\sigma(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$ (which in this case is the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue of $A$), and $\|A\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Av\|$ 
is the operator norm of $A$.

Does anyone see how to prove (or disprove) this statement?

Many thanks,

Ilya.

Comment: What about $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n\\ 1 &1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: You can (and should) use $\TeX$ in your questions, answers and comments.

Comment: @abx I think that for those of us who grew up reading formulas typed in raw form and who wish to avoid the page jerking as loads of MathJax crunches, it is not such a big ideal. But I am prepared to accept I am in the minority

Comment: Oops, ah, you are right of course. I guess that was just wishful thinking.

Comment: Of course, the bound $\sigma(A)\le ||A||$ is obvious, and in your example $||A||$ is bounded above by a quadratic polynomial in terms of $\sigma(A)$. So it may still be the case that for every $d$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ (maybe even of degree $d$) such that for every positive $d\times d$ integer matrix $A$ one has $||A||\le p(\sigma(A))$. Or is even this weaker statement still false?

Comment: A slightly different way to view Mike's counterexample: if such a bound were true for positive matrices, then by taking limits it would also hold for positive semi-definite matrices, and then a nilpotent matrix would be a counterexample.  But this also suggests that one can salvage some bound if one also controlled the condition number of the matrix.  Indeed, since the product of the absolute values of the eigenvalues is equal to the product of the singular values (both are equal to $|\hbox{det}(A)|$), one can get some inequality involving the condition number.

Comment: (correction: "positive" should be "positive integer entry", and "positive semi-definite" should be "nonnegative real entry", and "taking limits" should be "rescaling and taking limits" (to first pass from integers to rationals).)

Comment: The weaker conjecture is also false; for instance, conjugate $\hbox{diag}(1,2)$ by a large element of $SL_2({\bf Z})$, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Note again that ill conditioning is the culprit.  For integer non-singular matrices one has $|\hbox{det}(A)| \geq 1$, which doesn't give the bounds you want, but may give some other useful inequality for you.

Comment: Gah, that example doesn't have all entries positive.  I don't think that's an essential obstacle, but it does make finding a counterexample trickier.  (For instance, the diagonal entries of A are bounded by the trace, which is bounded by d times the spectral radius.)  It may be that one has to go to higher dimensions to find a counterexample.

Comment: In fact, your weaker conjecture is true!  Let $a_{ij}$ be the $ij$ component of $A$, then $A e_j \geq a_{ij} e_i$ and $A e_i \geq e_j$ using the product partial ordering on ${\bf R}^d$.  Iterating, we have $A^{2n} e_j \geq a_{ij}^n e_j$ for any $n$; sending $n$ to infinity we conclude that $a_{ij} \leq \sigma(A)^2$, and so $\|A\| \leq d \sigma(A)^2$ by Schur's test.

Comment: @TerryTao - Nice! I had suspected the weaker conjecture might be true by some kind of compactness argument but couldn't make it go.

Comment: Thanks, Terry! I came up with a different, more ad hoc, argument, which produced a polynomial upper bound on $||A||$ in terms of $\sigma(A)$, but the degree of that polynomial depended on the size $d$ of the matrix. It is rather remarkable that your argument produces a quadratic upper bound in every dimension. Thanks again!

Comment: Quite interesting, given that it is well-known that $1/2 \|A\| \le w(A) \le \|A\|$, where $w(A)$ is the numerical radius of matrix $A$ (and clearly, $\sigma(A) \le w(A)$)...

Comment: @Geoff: To be more precise, Terry's argument works for any matrix $A$ which has all $a_{ij}\ge 1$ (and where the entries do not have to be integers).

Comment: It's also interesting that integrality plays a role: I had noticed earlier the tweaking Mike Jury's example to $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 1 & n\\ \frac{1}{n} & 1 \end{array}\right)$ gives a matrix $A$ with $\sigma(A) =  2$ and $\|A \| > n,$ but of course $A$ is no longer integral.

Answer (score 9):

In fact, one can improve a little bit Terry's bound to show that
$\|A\|\le(\sigma(A))^2$, and therefore
  $$ \sigma(A) \le \|A\| \le (\sigma(A))^2. $$
Indeed, this is an immediate consequence of [the fact](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165628/9924) that for a
matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ with positive integer entries one has
$(\sigma(A))^2\ge\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}$, and the observation that if
$x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a unit-length vector, then
  $$ \|Ax\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j \Big)^2
              \le \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \Big)^2
              \le \Big( \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} \Big)^2, $$
implying $\|A\|\le \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}$.

Notice that by [Mike Jury](https://mathoverflow.net/users/13360/mike-jury)'s example above, with $\sigma(A)=\sqrt n+1$
and $\|A\|>n$, the estimate $\|A\|\le(\sigma(A))^2$ is
essentially best possible.

Also notice that the argument just presented actually works for any matrix $A$ with all entries greater than or equal to $1$; the assumption that the entries are
integer is not really used.